# Convert a mutable collection to an immutable collection in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there a generic way to convert some mutable collection in Scala to its immutable counterpart (assuming it has one)?

Example use case...

```
private[this] val _collection: mutable.TreeSet[A]

def collection: immutable.TreeSet[A] = {
  // convert mutable _collection to immutable version for public consumption
}
```

I tried the following...

```
def collection: immutable.TreeSet[A] = {
  _collection.to[immutable.TreeSet[A]]
}
```

...but that led to a cryptic error message on compilation...

```
scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[A] takes no type parameters, expected: one
```

...any thoughts?

Comment: `to` requires a type constructor e.g. `_collection.to[immutable.TreeSet]`.

Comment: @Lee, I tried this and got the following compilation error: `Cannot construct a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[A] with elements of type A based on a collection of type Nothing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the `immutable.TreeSet` has to be created from scratch:

```
  trait Aaa[A] {
    val _collection: mutable.TreeSet[A]

    def collection: immutable.TreeSet[A] = {
      immutable.TreeSet.empty[A] ++ _collection
    }
  }
```

---

**EDIT** to followup the comment

From the scala-2.11.7 source code of `immutable.TreeSet`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{RedBlackTree => RB}

private def newSet(t: RB.Tree[A, Unit]) = new TreeSet[A](t)
```

Unfortunately `newSet` is private and from `mutable.TreeSet`:

```
class TreeSet[A] private (treeRef: ObjectRef[RB.Tree[A, Null]], from: Option[A], until: Option[A])
```

The constructor is private too...

Comment: This works. I wonder why it is not possible to use the `to[Col]` method? Perhaps because I am trying to do this with an ordered collection.

Comment: Not sure. For both `mutable` and `immutable` `TreeSet` the underlying datastructure is a `scala.collection.immutable.RedBlackTree`!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the particular `Set` implementation you get in the end, the way to go is just `val immutableSet = mutableSet.toSet`

If you do specifically want immutable `TreeSet`, not just any `Set`, you will need to use breakOut:

```
val immutableSet: immutable.TreeSet[T] = mutableSet.map(identity)(collection.breakOut)
```

Comment: I do want to insure that the public view into the private sorted collection maintains the sorted order.  I worry that using `toSet` might not maintain the underlying order.  Is your suggestion more efficient than the current accepted answer? Seems like current answer is O(n log n). The `map` in your solution is O(n). Don't know what performance characteristics are for `breakOut`...

Comment: @davidrpugh I  think, complexity is the same, this is just a little shorter and more idiomatic. 
Also, consider this: `def collection: collection.SortedSet[A] = _collection.clone`
This gives you an immutable view in constant time.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your the use of `clone`? This looks exactly like what a wanted: an immutable view of mutable data as efficiently as possible.

Comment: mutable.TreeSet is a subclass of collection.SortedSet, so you can use the former as the latter without any conversions. `collection.SortedSet` is also immutable at the API level (there are no exposed mutators), which is what you want. You could just return the  underlying collection itself, but you don't want the caller's view to change when your collection is changed. Thus the need of clone. Scala's clone is constant time, it will copy segments of the tree as necessary lazily, when they change.